# How to remove password hint from an input

Tags: html, passwords

I am trying to get the password hint from the password change field, I already tried to disable the auto complete with the code

```
autocomplete="new-password" // or autocomplete="off"
```

but this does not work, does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Edit:

My problem is when I try to change the password, my password change screen, auto completion puts the old password as a new password, all standard means have been discarded, apparently google does not care what you want.

[image: Change password image]

Comment: Please post the whole element so we can view any additional properties that are set. In addition, do you mind clarifying? I am not certain what you are trying to do, and others may feel the same way.

Comment: Where in your example does the value for the password hint sit?

Comment: here:  <input type="password" class="form-control" name="NewPassword" autocomplete="off" id="NewPassword" data-object="AlterarSenha" data-field="NewPassword" />

Comment: So the value you would like is AlterarSenha?

Comment: the element has no value set, if it sets it to value = "" also does not work, I want to disable autoComplete

Answer (score 1):

You can use the onFocus event to the password field.

```
<input type="password" onfocus="this.value=''" ... />
```

Comment: I tried but it did not work

Answer (score 1):

One suggested solution is to use `autocomplete="new-password"` and if that does not work for you, then you may try `autocomplete="false"`. Do note that `autocomplete="false"` does not adhere to the official standards but is a known workaround.

Comment: I tried declaring both form and input but it did not work as well

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding `autocomplete="off"` to your form and `autocomplete="none"` to your inputs like it's mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50150105/9801177) answer

Comment: does not work too